# consider x^i+y^i=z^i, x<=y<=z<=m and 2<=i<=n (m and n are inputs) m can vary from 5 to 100 n can vary from 2 to 100

Tags: python, c, optimization

consider x^i+y^i=z^i, x<=y<=z<=m and 2<=i<=n (m and n are inputs) m can vary from 5 to 100 n can vary from 2 to 100

Here's the c program for it

```
int main()
{
  int m, n;
  long long int x, y, z, j;
  long long int xe, ye, ze, se;
  long long int sum = 0;
  scanf("%d", &m);
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for (j = 2; j <= n; j++)
  {
    for (x = 0; x <= m; x++)
    {
      for (y = x; y <= m; y++)
      {
        for (z = y; z <= m; z++)
        {
          xe = pow(x, j);
          ye = pow(y, j);
          ze = pow(z, j);
          se = (xe + ye);
          if (ze == se)
          {
            printf("\n i = %lld", j);
            sum++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  printf("sum= %lld ", sum);
  return 0;
}
```

as it wasn't working for large values(i didn't want to use big integer :P)
I wrote a python equivalent of it---

```
import math
m=0 
n=0 
x=y=z=j=0
xe=ye=ze=se=0
sum=0;  
m = int(input("Enter a number: "))
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))   

for j in range (2, n):

  for x in range (0, m):

    for y in range (x, m):

        for z in range (y, m):
            xe=math.pow(x,j)
            ye=math.pow(y,j)
            ze=math.pow(z,j)
            se=(xe+ye)
            if (ze == se): 
                sum=sum+1
print "sum=", sum
```

but it is also not working. Can anyone tell why?

Comment: If you want to do that in python, I suggest removing the C code and C tag ... you already asked exactly that question for C. I *guess* for exact results, you'd need *some* extra big-int support in python, too, so it would be **exactly the same problem** in a different language (but that's just a guess, I don't use python normally)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you heard of [Fermat's Last Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem)

Comment: `math.pow` is a floating point function. Don't use that if you need precise values (and you do due to using `==`). Just use integer power `x**y`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Python's ints are arbitrary precision; no need for extra big-int support.

Comment: @MarkDickinson ok, so it's just the floating-point function used here. Nevertheless, this should be a python-only question, as the same question for C was already there ...

Comment: Can you write this in python and comment it below please.? idont know python. i just googled stuffs and wrote.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Agreed about the Python-only part.

Comment: @JohnWick: Please can you edit the question to say in what way your code isn't working?  If it gives an error, please show the traceback.  If it's giving results that you think are incorrect, please show the inputs, the results you're getting, and say what results you expect.

Comment: I killed your puppy... what are you going to do about it?

Comment: I have no problem running it your python program. I'll post the code I'm using as an answer, it may be that I fixed some syntax error you had.

Comment: If a question title starts with 'consider', it's 99% certain to suck and require an immediate downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a popular math theorem - [Fermat's Great (Last) Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) - that states for any integer `n > 2` **there does not exist** non-zero integers `a`, `b`, `c` such that `a^n + b^n = c^n`.

Comment: Careful! You need to exclude trivial solutions.  (E.g., `a = c`, `b = 0`.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson fixed. I am better at coding that at accurate maths)

Answer (score 0):

You have have just had a syntax error. Here's what's working for me:

```
import math
m=0 
n=0 
x=y=z=j=0
xe=ye=ze=se=0
sum=0;  
m = int(input("Enter a number: "))
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))   

for j in range (2, n):

  for x in range (0, m):

    for y in range (x, m):

        for z in range (y, m):
            xe=x**j
            ye=y**j
            ze=z**j
            se=(xe+ye)
            if (ze == se): 
                sum=sum+1
print ("sum = "+str(sum))
```

I'm testing with inputs `m = 100` `n = 10` and I get `850` as the result.

Though, if you're trying to test Fermat's Last Theorem:

```
import math
m=0 
n=0 
x=y=z=j=0
xe=ye=ze=se=0
sum=0;  
m = int(input("Enter a number: "))
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))   

for j in range (3, n):

  for x in range (1, m):

    for y in range (x, m):

        for z in range (y, m):
            xe=x**j
            ye=y**j
            ze=z**j
            se=(xe+ye)
            if (ze == se): 
                sum=sum+1
print ("sum = "+str(sum))
```

use that ^.